# Search, Add and update using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need the ability to track work items by ServerGroup. Each ServerGroup may have multiple FaultCodes.

What is the best XML layout should I use?  **Option A or B?**  I was able to create a linq query to search on Option A.  But I wasn't sure how to then check the Fault Code.  So, I thought Option B, as it would allow me to group ServerGroup and FaultCode.  Is it possible to execute a linq search when them xml is structured like Option B?

Thanks for the assistance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CapacityIssues xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    **//Option A**
    <TrackingDetails>
        <ServerGroup>A</ServerGroup>
        <FaultCode>123</FaultCode>
        <ID>4123567</ID>
        <Title>Capacity Issues</Title>
        <AssignedTo>Team A</AssignedTo> 
        <Description>Server Group A has an issue</Description>
        <State>Active</State>
        <Priority>2</Priority>
    </TrackingDetails>

     **//Option B**
    <TrackingDetails ServerGroup="A" FaultCode="123">
        <ID>4123567</ID>
        <Title>Capacity Issues</Title>
        <AssignedTo>TeamA</AssignedTo>
        <Description>This is a test</Description>
        <State>Active</State>
        <Priority>0</Priority>
    </TrackingDetails>

</CapacityIssues>
```

I was able to search using Option A, here is the code that I wrote.

public static Dictionary> TFS(string filePath)
    {
        //sets the document type to read
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

```
    //execute reading of xml document
    if (doc == null || doc.Root == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Null document loaded from {filePath}");
    }

    return doc.Root.Elements("TfsDetails").ToDictionary(r => 
        r.Element("ServerGroup").Value,
        r => Tuple.Create(
            r.Element("FaultCode").Value, 
            r.Element("ID").Value, 
            r.Element("Title").Value, 
            r.Element("AssignedTo").Value, 
            r.Element("Description").Value, 
            r.Element("State").Value, 
            r.Element("Priority").Value
            ));
}
```

Here is how I added Option B Element to the XML file

```
private static void Create(string filePath)
{
    //load xml file
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    //xmnl header
    XElement root = new XElement("CapacityIssues");

    //node root
    root.Add(new XAttribute("ServerGroup", "A"));

    //cluster and TFS details
    root.Add(new XAttribute("FaultCode", "111"));
    root.Add(new XElement("ID", "4123567"));
    root.Add(new XElement("Title", "Capacity Issues"));
    root.Add(new XElement("AssignedTo", "Team A"));
    root.Add(new XElement("Description", "ServerGroup A has an issue"));
    root.Add(new XElement("State", "Active"));
    root.Add(new XElement("Priority", "0"));

    //add new element
    doc.Element("CapacityIssues").Add(root);

    //save xml file
    doc.Save(filePath);
}
```

Comment: i find the option b less verbose than the A for the xml part.  Surely,using XDoc n XElement, it would be easy to model that.

Comment: is this supposed to be `XElement root = new XElement("TrackingDetails "); `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though both are valid, of course, but recommendation is Option B (use attributes rather than element) as it has less depth.

You can use linq for `Attributes` as below.

```
foreach (var xAttribute in root.Descendants("TrackingDetails").Attributes().Where(o => o.Name.Equals("ServerGroup")))
{
    // do something about ServerGroup A or B
}
```